# SQL: Combine multiple rows into a single row with more columns

Tags: sql

I have a dataset structured like this:

```
ID  |  Feedback type  |  Feedback value
1      Overall rating    5 
1      Duration          23.5
1      Representative    Steve
2      Overall rating    4 
2      Duration          47
2      Representative    Jane
```

Essentially, each set of three rows represents a single interaction.  What I want is a single row for each interaction, like this:

```
ID  |  Overall rating  |  Duration | Representative
1      5                  23.5       Steve
2      4                  47         Jane
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out the right way to make a subquery that will do this.  In Excel, I'd just get a list of my IDs and do vlookups into the raw table, but I'm not clear how to do that in SQL.  Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: What you want to do is *pivot* the data.  Some databases have special syntax.  All support conditional aggregation.

Comment: Google "convert rows to columns " + your RDBMS and you will get plenty of examples.   If I knew your RDBMS, I could flag the appropriate duplicate here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the ideal way to do it

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
PIVOT(MAX([Feedback value])
      FOR [Feedback type] IN ([Overall rating], [Duration], [Representative])
     ) AS PVTTable
```

However, user is not able to use pivot, so this will work as well

```
SELECT [ID], 
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Feedback type] = 'Overall rating' 
                THEN [Feedback value] 
                ELSE '' END) AS 'Overall Rating',
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Feedback type] = 'Duration' 
                THEN [Feedback value] 
                ELSE '' END) AS 'Duration',
       MAX(CASE WHEN [Feedback type] = 'Representative' 
                THEN [Feedback value] 
                ELSE '' END) AS 'Representative'
FROM TableName
GROUP BY [ID]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm actually on a semi-limited version of SQL that doesn't include the Pivot function -- is there any alternative to what you just suggested?

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would have taken a different path:

```
SELECT T0.ID, T0.[Overall Rating], T1.Duration, T2.Representative

FROM (SELECT ID, [Feedback Value] AS 'Overall Rating' where [Feedback Type] = 'Overall Rating' FROM TableName) T0

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, [Feedback Value] AS 'Duration' where [Feedback Type] = 'Duration' FROM TableName) T1 ON T0.id = T1.id

LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, [Feedback Value] AS 'Representative' where [Feedback Type] = 'Representative' FROM TableName) T2 ON T0.id = T2.id
```

Essentially, I'm creating "Sub tables" to query from -- one each for ratings, durations, and representatives. Because they're all linked to the same ID, you can create the table and then join them. Of course, this isn't going to be the most efficient method to create this query if it's a large table, but for something small like your example, it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help.